# Why are my Vectors making duplicates?

Tags: java, vector

I would like to know why are my vectors making duplicates? I know i can use ArrayList, but this is a test for my blackberry app that only uses vectors at the moment. This is the result i continue to get:

```
ID:3 and Name:Catty and Price:100 and Msg:Catty is a preety girl
ID:3 and Name:Catty and Price:100 and Msg:Catty is a preety girl
ID:3 and Name:Catty and Price:100 and Msg:Catty is a preety girl
```

Here is the code, **testapp.java**

```
package testing;

import java.util.Vector;


public class testapp {
    private static Vector<String> listElements= new Vector<String>();
    private static Vector<String> listName= new Vector<String>();
    private static Vector<Integer> listPrice= new Vector<Integer>();
    private static Vector<String> listDate= new Vector<String>();
    private static Vector<String> listAbstract= new Vector<String>();
    private static Vector<rec> a = new Vector<rec>();
    static rec record = new rec();

    public static void main(String[] args){

        vectorBuilder();
        recordBuilder();
        showElements();

    }

    public static void recordBuilder(){

        try{
            for(int i=0;i<listElements.size();i++){
                record.setId((String) listElements.elementAt(i));
                record.setName((String) listName.elementAt(i));
                record.setDate((String) listDate.elementAt(i));
                record.setPrice(((Integer) listPrice.elementAt(i)).intValue());
                record.setAbstract((String) listAbstract.elementAt(i));
                a.addElement(record);   
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Record Builder Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void vectorBuilder(){
        //Ben
        listElements.addElement("1");
        listName.addElement("Ben");
        listPrice.addElement(502);
        listDate.addElement("2012-05-12");
        listAbstract.addElement("Ben is a Good Boy");

        //Kesha
        listElements.addElement("2");
        listName.addElement("Kesha");
        listPrice.addElement(367);
        listDate.addElement("2012-02-24");
        listAbstract.addElement("Kesha Works hard in her school work");

        //Catty
        listElements.addElement("3");
        listName.addElement("Catty");
        listPrice.addElement(100);
        listDate.addElement("2012-01-04");
        listAbstract.addElement("Catty is a preety girl");


    }

    public static void showElements(){
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        {
            rec r = (rec) a.elementAt(i);
            System.out.println("ID:"+r.getId()+" and Name:"+r.getName()+" and Price:"+r.getPrice()+" and Msg:"+r.getAbstract());
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the **rec.java**

```
package testing;


public class rec {
        String name;
        String id;
        String date;
        String strAbstract;
        int price;


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }
        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        public String getAbstract() {
            return strAbstract;
        }
        public void setAbstract(String strAbstract) {
            this.strAbstract = strAbstract;
        }

        public int getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
        public void setPrice(int price) {
            this.price = price;
        }


}
```

Comment: You have an extra ; after private static Vector<String> listElements= new Vector<String>();;

Comment: thanks user1394965 for noticeing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create new rec while calling `recordBuilder`. If you don't create new `record` same instance will be updated which is why you are getting duplicates.

```
for(int i=0;i<listElements.size();i++){
                rec record = new rec();
                record.setId((String) listElements.elementAt(i));
                record.setName((String) listName.elementAt(i));
                record.setDate((String) listDate.elementAt(i));
                record.setPrice(((Integer) listPrice.elementAt(i)).intValue());
                record.setAbstract((String) listAbstract.elementAt(i));
                a.addElement(record);   
            }
```

Note: Java naming convention suggests that class name starts with capital letter. `Record` may be good name than `rec`.

Comment: thanks alot for the advice on standards. :-)